# Unable to launch the requested CGI program: /www/cgi-bin/first.cgi: Text file busy

Tags: shell-script, openwrt, cgi, uhttpd

I'm trying to make a very simple shell script to run as a CGI on a uhttpd server running on an OpenWRT install.

The file is called `/www/cgi-bin/first.cgi` and looks like...

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Bash as CGI"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "<h1>Hello world</h1>"
echo "Today is $(date)"
echo "</body></html>"
```

...and I did a

```
chmod +x first.cgi
```

on the file.

When I try to pull up...

```
http://192.168.15.1/cgi-bin/first.cgi
```

...the browser gets...

```
Unable to launch the requested CGI program:
/www/cgi-bin/first.cgi: Text file busy"
```

I can `cat` and `vi` the file from a shell prompt, so not sure how the file is busy or even how I would find out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. What does your apache log say? 2. Does it work if you go to the directory where the script lives and try to run it using `./first.cgi`?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'm guessing that filesystem `/www` is mapped to `http://servername/` root, which means that folder `/www/cgi-bin/` maps to `http://servername/cgi-bin/` and thus you should be hunting for `http://servername/cgi-bin/first.cgi` instead.

It also might be that the http server process cannot read, even if you can. The file mode should be `555 (r-xr-xr-x)` or `550 (r-xr-x---)` depending on if the file group ownership is for the group that httpd is in.

Another possibility is that the $(date) requires a shell-external command, that might not be available at runtime. Do try without that.

Still not working? The server might be picky about where it allows CGI execution. Usually only `http://servername/cgi-bin/` is allowed, meaning you're in the right place at filename /www/cgi-bin/first.cgi. [uHTTPd documentation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/uhttpd) seems to want the CGI folder set or else it'll not allow CGI at all. Do check this from the configuration file.

Please note that I'm answering from a generic Unixy background, not knowing very much about OpenWRT or uHTTPd specifics. I do have several decades Unix/Linux background and the generic architecture is very familiar to me.

Comment: I'd guess it's the permissions problem - I saw that the poster had used chmod but missed that it didn't include group/others.

Comment: (BTW, your name will be appended to every answer and question here, so you don't need to add a sign-off.)

Comment: Thanks @JennyD, I'm new in here so I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Well, you started out with a very good answer so I should think it won't take very long for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The (embarrassing) answer is that I had been using CAT the create the file and pressing Control-Z to finish. Control-Z only pushes the CAT job into the background, so the CAT still had the file open. Using the Control-D keystroke to finish CATing into the file correctly closes the file and gets rid of the "Text File Busy" error.

Comment: To detect which programs might have a particular file open, try:

`fuser -v /www/cgi-bin/first.cgi`